# Array of unicode char to string : strange behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to reduce the size of my Fontawesome icon fonts.
First I parse my css file for retrieving all the unicode codes
with

```js
    const numericValue = parseInt(unicodeHex, 16)
    const character = String.fromCharCode(numericValue)
    glyphList.push(character)
```

Next I generate a string with

```js
    const glyphListStr = glyphlist.join(' ')
    console.log(glyphListStr)
```

It gives       (tested it contains \uF5EC \uE00F \uF4CD \uE022 \uE2CE \uF3CA ) it is OK

My strange behavior.
**Working code**

```js
    const fontmin = new Fontmin()
        .use(Fontmin.glyph({
            text: '     ' ,//glyphListStr
            hinting: false
            }))
```

**But when I use the variable it fails:
What I make wrong?**

```js
    const fontmin = new Fontmin()
        .use(Fontmin.glyph({
            text:  glyphListStr, //'     '
            hinting: false
            }))
```

Answer (score 0):

After many hours I decided to upgrade my typescript to 4.8.2
and I cannot understand why but now it is working !
It was probably a wrong type somewhere.